# Как округлить выводимое число

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть блок, который выводит число такого рода `7.358`. 
Как мне округлить его до `7.3`?

```
<div class="foreign-rating orientation-vertical">
     <span class="value" data-select-link-text="1">7.358</span> 
     <span class="key">КП</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если задача стоит изменить до 1 значения после запятой, то можете попробовать так:

```js
console.log(7.358.toFixed(1))
console.log(7.358.toPrecision(2))
```

Но данный пример округлит число до 7.4 в большую сторону. Если нужно оставить именно 7.3 без округления, то можно сделать так как вариант:

```js
console.log((parseInt(7.358 * 10)) / 10)
```

Все остальные методы округления, будут возвращать 7.4. Ваш код обновляющий значение после вывода:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.value');
elem.innerText = (parseInt(elem.innerText * 10)) / 10;
```

```html
<div class="foreign-rating orientation-vertical">
        <span class="value" data-select-link-text="1">7.358</span> <span class="key">КП</span>
    </div>
```